# How to force weights to be non-negative in Linear regression only with Numpy

Tags: python, regression, numpy

My question is the same as here:
[How to force weights to be non-negative in Linear regression](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/18258/how-to-force-weights-to-be-non-negative-in-linear-regression)

Except that I can only use Numpy (I cannot use Scipy or Scikit Learn).
Indeed, I am running my Python script on a server which doesn't include these modules.

Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

The sklearn implementation of Lasso that can force non-negative weights (as in [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/19791/24162)) is based on the [coordinate descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_descent) algorithm. You can reimplement it, using for example coordinate-wise [Newton method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization). For simplicity, I did not inclide intercept into the model:

```
import numpy as np
# generate the data
np.random.seed(1)
n = 1000
X = np.random.normal(size=(n, 5))
y = np.dot(X, [0,0,1,2,3]) + np.random.normal(size=n, scale=3)
# initial solution (with some negative weights):
beta = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(np.dot(X.transpose(),X)), np.dot(X.transpose(), y))
print(beta)
# clip the solution from below with zero
prev_beta = beta.copy()
beta = np.maximum(beta, 1)
# improve the solution by restricted coordinate-wise Newton descent
hessian = np.dot(X.transpose(), X)
while not (prev_beta == beta).all():
    prev_beta = beta.copy()
    for i in range(len(beta)):
        grad = np.dot(np.dot(X,beta)-y, X)
        beta[i] = np.maximum(0, beta[i] - grad[i] / hessian[i,i])
print(beta)
```

This code will output initial and final beta's:

```
[-0.01404546 -0.02633036  1.06028543  1.99696564  2.93511618]
[ 0.          0.          1.05919989  1.99673774  2.93442334]
```

You can see that OLS beta differ from your optimal beta not only in the first two coefficients (that have been negative), but the rest of coefficients were also adjusted.